# Writing data to remote mongodb database

Tags: java, mongodb, networking, mongodb-query

I am reading a CSV file line by line and upserting data to mongodb database. It takes 2 mins approx. to read, process and write data to mongodb from all files, when db and the files are on same machine. Whereas when the db is located on another machine in my network, it takes around 5 mins.  It is taking even more time on remote machine. can anyone please help me out to reduce time ?. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure for mongo, but can you create batch for each entry and insert all entry batch only at on time.

Comment: How does the insertion code look like? What kind of inserts, which write concerns, etc. - give us some material to work with.

Answer (score 0):

An approach to your problem with reduction in processing time.

To Read the CSV file and put it into MongoDB Use an ETL such as Kettle.

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Write+Data+To+MongoDB

This will enhance the time in reading from CSV to writing in MongoDB.

Simplest way to have the data in the remote machine.

Export the Data in your local db and import it in the remote machine.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/core/import-export/

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you are using Java to load your Mongo database.

The Java driver on recent version allow bulk operations, so you can send a batch of insert to mongo instead of sending them one by one. This will speed up inserts in mongoDB a lot.

```
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("my_collection");
List<DBObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    //generate your datas
    BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject("key", "value");
    list.add(obj);
}
collection.insert(list);//bulk insert of 100 obj!
```

This is available since Mongo 2.6 : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.insert/

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for all your answers. But bulk write/insert is not the solution in my case because some of the csv lines in my file are inter-dependent. Anyway, my point is why it is taking a longer amount of time when the application and db are on different servers?. Is it because of network latency? If yes, how to reduce that?. Completely lost on this. Not sure where to look for the solution.

Comment: Hello, yes, sure, when it's not on the same machine, network latency will impact the performance and it's not related to mongodb so there will not be anything easy you can do about it. If you want to use the same code as you use locally but remotely and speed up this code so it's as performant as locally ... there is no solution (or use a bigger machine with a bigger network)
The only way to boost up mongodb insert is via bulk insert as it will lower the number of network roundtrip.